# @font-face don't works just inline font-family

Tags: html, css, fonts, phpmailer

I need your help, I'm trying to change the font for an email in PHPMAILER, and just recognize the inline css, style tag in the head dont works (I don't know why).

You know how can I do for insert the @font-face inline the tbody?

```
$contenido = '<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: dinot-regularregular;
        src: url(xxxxxxxxxxxx/css/Font/dinot-regular-webfont.woff);
    }
    body {
        font-family: dinot-regularregular;
    }
        </style>
      </head>

    <body>';
$contenido .= '
<table> 
<tbody style="font-family:dinot-regularregular; font-size:16px; color:#666666;">
// Content
</tbody>
</table>';
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't think that is going to work. Or you could try to include the font files in the email itself.

Comment: be sure your browser/email client supports the embedded font woff format...

Comment: @putvande I'm already try that, don't works.

Comment: @shennan yeah, works with normal fonts, not custom like this.

Answer (score 0):

Formatted emails are very finicky with support from email clients. If you read this article they have a table showing how many email clients support font-face. It's not a very high number.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3044/does-font-face-work-in-email

Comment: Hehe.. was just looking at the same website

Comment: All right, nothing to do, many thanks.
If I can make that works, You will know !